# Windows Server 2008 R2 Domain Controller DNS Reverse lookup zone needed?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

When I create a new Domain Controller with dcpromo then the wizard will also add a DNS Role to the server because the first domain controller must be the global catalog server for the forest.

After the install when I look at the DNS then I see the forward lookup zone for the newly created domain.

However no zone is created for the Reverse lookup zone.

So my question is: Is this an advisable endresult or not? In other words is it a good idea to add my domain to the reverse lookup zone as well?

Just curious to hear how other people use this zone in the domain controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reverse lookup zone is not a requirement for AD and has no bearing on the operation of AD. As such, a rDNS zone isn't created as a part of the DCPROMO process. You can choose to create a rDNS zone for your subnet(s) or not, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok clear! :) Then I'm not going to create that zone for the fun of it! Good to hear that its non-essential. Thanks for your answer and have a good one!

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: fwiw I like having a reverse lookup zone just so that when someone gives me an IP address I can very quickly see which DNS name it maps to.

Comment: I normally set up reverse lookup zones as well, but I wanted to answer the question as directly as possible.

Comment: Hi Mark and joe, Ok setting it up for such a purpose is at least a useful purpose. (although we have tracert too :) ) Ok now I have one I'm going to create it too! Thanks guys!

Comment: Glad to help, Joost